# how to convert string as qwidget in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.6, qt5.7

How to convert string as qwidget in qt. Dynamically have to access.. Any other method is having to convert string to QWidget.

Sample code:

```
QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget();
QWidget *widget2 = new QWidget();

QPushButton *next = new QPushButton("next");
QPushButton *prev = new QPushButton("prev");

stack->addWidget(widget1);
stack->addWidget(widget2);

stack->setCurrentIndex(0);

QObject::connect(next, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(NextBt()));

QObject::connect(prev, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PrevBt()));

void MainWindow::NextBt()
{

std::string str1 = "widget" + std::to_string(1);
QString str = str1.c_str();    // "widget1"

//How to implement QWidget object as conversion of String here.
//for dynamically i want to remove the already added widget.

stack->removeWidget(str);
str->deleteLater();
stack->setCurrentIndex(1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QWidget *your_widget = parentWidget->findChild<QWidget *>("widget1");

if(your_widget != 0)
{
    //do whatever you want
}
```

See [QObject::findChild()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

> Returns the child of this object that can be cast into type T and that
>   is called name, or 0 if there is no such object. Omitting the name
>   argument causes all object names to be matched...

Do not forget to set a parent for the widgets you want to find. It is also necessary set a name for the object. For example

```
QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget(this);
widget1->setObjectName("widget1");
```

You can check *all the children* of some widget using [QObject::findChildren()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

> Returns all children of this object with the given name that can be
>   cast to type T, or an empty list if there are no such objects...

You can also get access to objects' methods by strings, for example:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(thread, "quit", // invoke the quit() method of QThread
                          Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

See [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

Comment: Hi Vladimir, m getting error of  **parentWidget->findChild**   how to detect the string is matched here already created that **widget1**..

Comment: Ok, this is because you didn't set a perent for your widgets. Do this: `QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget(this);`

Comment: oh thanks Vladimir, QMetaObject::invoke method is used for method calling as string i used and works.. **But we can use string as QWidget.. Sorry, i can't find a solution this one ?** i have strucked here.. can u help me some what detail.

Comment: @SenthilKumar , ok, you need to add `widget1->setObjectName("widget1");`

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, Very useful comments for me.